# access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'xxxx_user'@'localhost' for table 'catalog_product_option'

Tags: magento-1.9

When I tried to add product from product details page, it showing a popup message

> 'Can not add this item to the shopping cart'.

Then when I go to list page it showing a MySQL violation error message.

=> I tried to rename `local.xml` file and again install a magento with same database.

=> Used database repair tools

=> changed `php.ini` memory limit values.

=> Update all products and it's attribute

But still facing same issue, Can you please suggest me what exactly happen?

Product detail page link : https://boilerplatecodes.com/laminath/zrich-40805.html

Comment: Please check system.log file if there is any error regarding this

Comment: Try switching to default theme?

Comment: The problem only happens once you try adding something to cart and the theme tries to render the mini cart. So my guess is you have something wrong with your theme

Comment: Yes trying to default theme, it's work fine on default theme

Comment: Can you post content of `/app/design/frontend/smartwave/laminaat/template/checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml`

Comment: Check the content of default.phtm file. https://boilerplatecodes.com/laminath/content.txt

Comment: Sorry, but whomever wrote or edited that file deserves ... You don't put queries in a phtml file! That code is nasty. It's not one error that needs to be fixed, the whole thing should be discarded. Do you have the original file?

Comment: Yes I have the orignal file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by removing all this code.

```
$query = "select `catalog_product_option_type_price`.`option_type_price_id`,    `catalog_product_option_type_price`.`option_type_id`,   `catalog_product_option`.`option_id`,   `catalog_product_option`.`product_id`,  `catalog_product_option`.`type`,    `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`sku`,  `catalog_product_option_type_price`.`price` from `laminaatspecialist`.`catalog_product_option`,`laminaatspecialist`.`catalog_product_option_type_price`,`laminaatspecialist`.`catalog_product_option_type_value` where `catalog_product_option`.`option_id` = `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_id` AND `catalog_product_option`.`product_id` = ".$productId." AND `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_id` = ".$optionId." AND `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_type_id` = `catalog_product_option_type_price`.`option_type_id`";      $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);       foreach($results as $result){           if($checkcat){              echo $option['label'] . ': ' .number_format((float)$result['price'], 2, '.', '')." cm";                 if($storeval == 'english'){                     echo $option['label'] . ': ' .number_format((float)$result['price'], 2, '.', '')."1 cm";                }           }else{              echo $option['label'] . ': ' .number_format((float)$result['price'], 2, '.', '')." mÂ²";            }       } }
```

Comment: It looks like you have same garbage queries in `/app/design/frontend/smartwave/laminaat/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`